# Getting CivicAddress on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, geolocation, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to get the CivicAddress from a Geoposition in Windows Phone 8.1

I've tried using the following code:

```
// Get Current Location
var geolocator = new Geolocator();
geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 100;
var position = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();

// Get Country
var country = position.CivicAddress.Country;
```

which throws NullReferenceException as the CivicAddress field is null. I understand that a CivicAddress provider is not provided for Windows 8. I would like to check whether this is the case for Windows Phone 8.1 If so, how can I obtain / write a CivicAddress provider?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will need to use ReverseGeocoding for this - some more information [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn631249.aspx).

As for *windows runtime* you can for example use [MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAtAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.services.maps.maplocationfinder.findlocationsatasync.aspx) for this purpose:

```
 var geolocator = new Geolocator();
 geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 100;
 Geoposition position = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();

 // reverse geocoding
 BasicGeoposition myLocation = new BasicGeoposition
     {
         Longitude = position.Coordinate.Longitude,
         Latitude = position.Coordinate.Latitude
     };
 Geopoint pointToReverseGeocode = new Geopoint(myLocation);

 MapLocationFinderResult result = await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAtAsync(pointToReverseGeocode);

 // here also it should be checked if there result isn't null and what to do in such a case
 string country = result.Locations[0].Address.Country;
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I've searched a while for the WinRT solution. This just works.

Comment: Here no need of crating new BasicGeoposition myLocation, can use directly position.Coordinate.Point as parameter to MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAtAsync();

Comment: @vITs You are right that in case you want to use current position, you can just pass the position directly. New *Geopoint* will be useful once you have longitude and latitude (for example from database or somewhere else).

Comment: yeah...in case you want other properties of position.Coordinate from DB.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get address for a position, then I would suggest you use ReverseGeocodeQuery API with the position you get with the Geolocator API, for reference implementation I do have an example available at github here https://github.com/nokia-developer/maps-samples/tree/master/RevGeoCoding

else you could also try this to get civic address from GeoCoordinates 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.civicaddress(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.civicaddress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)