# Get Coordinates/Geopoint for given CivicAddress on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, navigation, geolocation, windows-phone-8.1, coordinates

From eveywhere I've looked I found how to get the `CivicAddress` of a specific set of coordinates, like so (thanks [@Romasz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23695748/1821647) for the answer):

```
var geolocator = new Geolocator();
geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 100;
Geoposition position = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();

// reverse geocoding
BasicGeoposition myLocation = new BasicGeoposition {
     Longitude = position.Coordinate.Longitude,
     Latitude = position.Coordinate.Latitude
};

Geopoint pointToReverseGeocode = new Geopoint(myLocation);
MapLocationFinderResult result = await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAtAsync(pointToReverseGeocode);

string country = result.Locations[0].Address.Country;
```

However, I have the `CivicAddress` but I need to know it's coordinates. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MapLocationFinderResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.services.maps.maplocationfinderresult.aspx) has some useful properties and you should be able to retrive the 
*GeoPoint* like this:

```
Geopoint point = result.Locations.FirstOrDefault().Point;
```

That's for the code from your question. However if you want to find something depending on its name, then you can use [MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn636927.aspx):

```
MapLocationFinderResult result = await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAsync("Hospital", myGeopoint, maxResults);
Geopoint point = result.Locations.FirstOrDefault().Point;
```

*GeoPoint* in this method is used as a helper - there may be many 'Hospitals' in area and the method should return the nearest one.

---

EDIT - some more information:

If you don't want to provide any starting *GeoPoint*, then provide the default one:

```
MapLocationFinderResult result = await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAsync("Lizbona", new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()), 5);
var point = result.Locations.ToList();
```

Remember the results depend on what you put in the string, for the above example I get two results - one in Portugal with geoposition `Lat = 38,72 Long = -9,15` and second in Poland with geoposition `Lat = 52,67 Long = 16,48` (which statnds for town in Poland). Both exist and both are correct - it just depends on your input. On the other hand if I search for `"Lizbon"` - I will get only one result, if `"Lisbon"` - four results. It probably will also depend on the user's language.

Comment: But from what I understood, you still need a `geopoint` to do that search. I have an Address and want to know what are the Coordinates for that address, pretty much what the Google Maps API does (see example [here](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Lisbon,%20Portugal&sensor=false)). Can I do this?

Comment: @ricochete I've added some more information in the answer. You can put any geopoint as a hint - it's only a hint -, but the results in some cases can be surprising as I think.

Comment: It does work, however if you're looking for a specific address with street name and number, sometimes it does not return anything. Still, better than nothing. I'll mark your reply as answer since it does work, but I guess that if you need more precise data (and a result for almost every address for that matter), the GoogleMaps API seems to handle the job well.

Comment: @ricochete I think it will depend on few things: what maps the user is using (loaded on phone0, if he allowed for online search, when the maps had been updated and so on. Those problems concern every  API as I think.

Comment: @Romasz : Is there any superior alternative to this API. Cause I've tried using this and for normal queries like "Bus","Buses", "Bus Stops" etc I don't get any results. For "Hospitals" I get a few results but they are not the close ones. They are randomly picked.

Comment: @AbsoluteSith It rather map's database rather than API, I'm not sure if it uses internet connection to check external databases. You may also try to download offline maps on your device and see if that helps. If not, maybe try different apis - google maps, openstreetmap.

Comment: @Romasz : Yeah I realized it later and now I'm using the Here maps for searching locations nearby. Thanks for your help.